# How to randomize array element positions of an `ActiveRecord::Relation`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, random

I am running Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to randomize array element *positions* of an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could always add `.order('random()')` to the relation:

```
ar = Model.where(...).where(...).order('random()')
```

You could even add that as a scope:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :randomize, order('random()')
end
```

There are a few things to be aware of:

1. PostgreSQL and SQLite use `random()`, MySQL uses `rand()`, I'm not sure about other databases.
2. `ORDER BY random()` can be quite expensive in the database so you don't want to use this unless your WHERE clauses (i.e. `.where` calls) will limit the size of the result set that you will be applying `ORDER BY random()` to.
3. A `.limit` will be applied *after* the ORDER BY so `x.limit(n).order('random()')` will apply the ORDER BY to all of `x` and then apply `limit(n)` after the sorting. This is where the warning in (2) comes from.

Comment: Is it different and/or important (relating to performance) if I state `x.limit(n).order('random()')` or `x.order('random()').limit(n)`? That is, those two statements are equal?

Comment: @Backo: Those are the same. All the AR relation stuff just builds an SQL query piece by piece so the actual order that things happen in depends solely on how the database (i.e. SQL) does it. That's why you don't want to `.order('random()')` unless you have a small table or your `.where()`s limit your result set to a small set of rows and why I included point (3).

Comment: *BTW*: How many records are considered a "small set"/"small table"?

Comment: @Backo: *small* depends on your application and database (as usual), I'd probably call thousands small.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to get an idea of what could be considered "small".

Answer (score 1):

Given that `Store.items` is a `has_many` relation, you can do

```
a = store.items.all.shuffle
```

Comment: At this time I cannot "try"/"run" your code... so, does the `shuffle` method return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`?

Comment: @Backo No, it will be an array.

Comment: @Backo I'm curious why you need to keep it in a `ActiveRecord::Relation` ?

Comment: Symply because you can use Ruby on Rails methods on that.